# Rails 3.2 self joins association works in console but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, self-join

I have a self joins in my Rails 3.2 app. It seems to work in the console, but in the view it seems like I don't have access to any association of the class_name. Here's my code:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :author, :class_name =>"User", :foreign_key => "author_id"

  def author_name
    author.profile.name
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

The difference above is that a profile has many comments about it. But a User can leave a comment about another Profile as an Author.

So if I'm in console and run something like:

```
Comment.first.author_name
```

I'll get a string result like "Test Author"

However if I call `<%= comment.author_name %>` in the partial _comment.html.erb which I render with @comments, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass):
```

I assign the `author_id` in `comments_controller` within the create action with this line:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment].merge(:author_id => current_user.id))
```

**The Profile and Comment Controllers:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save!
      @profile = @comment.profile
      Resque.enqueue(CommentWorker, @comment.id)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'fail.js.erb' }
      end
    end
  end
end

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@profile.user_id)
    @comments = @profile.comments
  end
end
```

**The views (in order of partial load:**

Within `profiles/_logged_in.html.erb` (which is called in `profiles/show.html.erb`)

```
<%= render :partial => 'profile_cred' %>
```

Within `profiles/_profile_cred_in.html.erb`

```
<% if current_user_profile?(@profile) %>
  <%= render :partial => "comments/auth_user_comments" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => "comments/user_comments" %>
<% end %>
```

Within `profiles/_auth_user_comments.html.erb`

```
<% if @comments.count == 0 %>
  <p id="commentIntro">You have no comments yet, <%= "#{@profile.first_name}" %>.</p>
<% elsif @comments.count > 0 %>
  <p id="commentIntro"><%= "#{@profile.first_name}" %>&nbsp;is most likely to:</p>&nbsp;<ul id="commentInfo"><%= render @comments, :locals => {:comment_count => @comments.length} %>
<% end %></ul>
```

Within `profiles/_user_comments.html.erb`

```
<div id="newComment">
  <p id="commentIntro"><%= @profile.first_name %> is:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => {profile: @profile} %>
</div>
<div id="list">
  <ul id="commentInfo">
    <% if @comments.count > 0 %>
      <%= render @comments %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Within `comments/_comment.html.erb`

```
<li id="<%= comment.id %>" class="comment">
  <span title="<%= comment.author_name %>"><%= comment.body %><% if current_user_profile?(@profile) %><p class="deleteSup"><%= link_to 'x', comment_path(comment.id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this comment?" %></p><% end %></span>
```

I'm at a loss as to why this works in console but not the view. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The error throws while rendering code for `comments/user_comments`, which is called if I'm viewing the comments I gave on another person's profile, for example. When I debug here's my output:

```
#<Comment id: 32, profile_id: 1, author_id: 45, body: "test", created_at: "2012-12-15 05:12:00", updated_at: "2012-12-15 05:12:00">, 
#<Comment id: nil, profile_id: 1, author_id: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

I thought this was caused by instantiating a new Comment in the form that lives in the `comments/user_comments` partial but I don't know. Here's that form code:

```
<% if logged_in? and not current_user_profile?(profile) %>
  <%= form_for(profile.comments.new, :remote => true, :html => {:id =>"new_comment"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :profile_id, :value => profile.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :author_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <div class="holds">
    <%= content_tag(:span, "ex: change the world", :class =>"holder_comment") %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :autofocus => true %>
  </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Add' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessible :author_id` in your model?

Comment: No, but I just tried adding it (to both `Comment` and `User`) and nothing changed in the view.

Comment: You may want to look into the delegate method: http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate it seems to be what you want but could we see how you are looping in the view?

Comment: Please show your Profle and User models code.

Comment: Have you done a check that there is a comment with an author_id that is nil or an author_id for an author that no longer exists?

Comment: In my opinion, the difference between your code in the console and in the view/controller, is that in the console you're working with a persisted object (a comment saved to the database), while, according to the code you're showing from your controller, the Comment there has not been persisted yet. Would be very helpful to see both your view and controller code to make a further judgement on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. In one of the partials I had a form for `@profile.comments.new`, which was initializing a nil Comment with a `profile_id`. So that was messing things up. Replacing it with `form_for Comment.new` and adding a `hidden_field` for `profile_id` helped.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write the code you have in the controller and the views as well? Also, can you debug what you have on @comments before you call the partial?

Before doing something like this in your view:

```
<%= render :partial => "comment", :collection => @products %>
```

Comment the code and do something like

```
<%= debug @products %>
<%# render :partial => "comment", :collection => @products %>
```

Also, you may want to try doing

```
<%# render :partial => "comment", :collection => @products.all %>
```

Because it might be that you are passing an ActiveRecord relationship instead of a collection of Products and that may be the erro

Comment: I've added a bunch more code. I thought I nabbed the error at first but my mind was just playing tricks on me.